# Why query is firing two times in wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress

I have written one code which will save the form data in database on submit...

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) {

    global $wpdb;
    $company_name = $wpdb->prefix . "company";
    $single_table = $wpdb->prefix . "single";
    $emp_table = $wpdb->prefix . "employee";
    $idea_table = $wpdb->prefix . "idea";

    if($_POST['team-type'] == "Freelancer"){
        $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $company_name (name, team_size) VALUES(%s, %d)", $_POST['cname'],1));  


        $company_id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT MAX(id) FROM wp_company" );
        echo "<h2>1</h2>";

        $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $single_table (company_id, name, bio,linkedin_url) VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %s)", $company_id, $_POST['freelancer-name'] ,$_POST['free-bio'], $_POST['free-url'] ) );

    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO $table_name (name, team_size) VALUES('" . $_POST['cname'] . "'," . $_POST['team'] .")";
        $wpdb->query($query);
        echo "<h2>2</h2>";
    }
    echo "<h2>3</h2>";
}
```

The problem is, in database the data is stored twice.

But the h2 tag which i put on page, that is showing only one time.

What's wrong in code or what should i do to save data only one time ?

BTW the if condition is also working fine, bcz i can check the h2 tags on based what i select ?

Comment: where is this code added? Is it a hook, in a function, or what?

Comment: no...its is as page post...

Answer (score 0):

Well at first, I would recommend using

```
$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

Instead of

```
$company_id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT MAX(id) FROM wp_company" );
```

But that's not the point I guess.

Other than that I would suggest using $wpdb->insert() for your queries. Because you are running plain simple queries. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows

And if that doesn't get you anywhere: the problem will be in client side. You are sending the request twice. So try installing Fiddler and sniffing how many requests you send.

Comment: but if request two time going, then i am not able to understand why, my h2 tag data is showing only once... ?? :(

Comment: because you only see the result of the last request, well basically you should just try looking IF the the second request is actually there, since I don't see any other way this could be wrong